# How to connect Vue3 in Vue2 using module federation?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, webpack-module-federation

I'm trying to module federate vue3 remote server on vue2 host server, is this possible?

I've confirmed the opposite is possible.
vue2 in vue3 is working, but vue3 in vue2 is not working

Is there a way to connect without upgrading the version?

Comment: I did not know you can connect Vue 2 with 3 (or vice versa), how are you doing it ? Is it possible to connect them in chain, like Vue 2 => Vue 3 => Vue 2 ?

Comment: I'm not very good at English. I would like to know if the components of a Vue3 remote server can be used on a Vue2 host server using module federation. I'm not asking if they can be connected, but if they can be used. I have checked the components of a Vue2 remote server because there is an example of using it with a Vue3 host server, and I am wondering if the opposite is also possible.

Example : https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/vue2-in-vue3
vue2 remote server -> vue3 host server = module federation OK
vue3 remote server -> vue2 host server = ?

Comment: The short answer would be `no` - you won't be able to easily use Vue3 component in a Vue2 application.

Comment: There is a library which allows universal vue libraries named `vue-demi`. Please check out